# Where to put ruby object extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to know where put monkey patching code like the following in my rails application which would open up existing classes and add or override new functionality.  I want this code to be available to all instances as soon as possible.  Is autoload the correct way of doing this and putting the call in environment.rb?

```
class Class
  def attr_initializer(*attributes)
    attr_reader *attributes
    class_eval <<-RUBY
      def initialize(#{attributes.join(', ')})
        #{attributes.map{ |attribute| "@#{attribute}" }.join(', ')} = #{attributes.join(', ')}
      end
    RUBY
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using rails 2.3.x then the standard place to put these is within a file in the config/initializers directory. Rails will load these files early in the boot process.

Comment: Thanks, how about when running tests, do I need to add any code in the test_helper to initialize this code also?

Comment: These initializers will be run when the test suite loads. The files in config/initialiers is run for all environments